# delete folder with wildcard using some variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

in Windows, when I want to delete several similar directories (with wildcard), I delete them with these commands:

Example folder:

```
c:\Users\user\folder\
   test1
   test2
   personalinfo
```

Example commands to delete folders with wildcard:

```
for /d %x in ("c:\Users\User\folder\test*") do rd /s /q "%x"
or
forfiles /P c:\Users\User\folder /M test* /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /s /q @file"
```

Result:

```
c:\Users\User\folder\
   personalinfo
```

But doesn't work with %HOMEPATH% variable

```
for /d %x in ("%HOMEPATH%\folder\test*") do rd /s /q "%x"
or
forfiles /P %HOMEPATH%\folder /M test* /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /s /q @file"
```

But with %APPDATA% (or %HOMEDRIVE%\Users\User\etc etc) works fine... very rare:

```
c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\folder\
   test1
   test2
   personalinfo

for /d %x in ("%APPDATA%\folder\test*") do rd /s /q "%x"
or
forfiles /P %APPDATA%\folder /M test* /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rmdir /s /q @file"

 c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\folder\
   personalinfo
```

Note: Test in Win 7. I'm not sure if the same thing happens in Windows 8/10

how can I solve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show me what result you get when you do `echo %homepath%`

Comment: echo %homepath%   \Users\User

Comment: No drive letter?

Comment: normal homedrive (c:)

Comment: Use `%USERPROFILE%` it's usually the combined `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`

Comment: @LotPings yes. that's the correct answer. replace %HOMEPATH% with %USERPROFILE%. Please put your answer explained to mark it as correct and thank you

Comment: As already informed `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` should work, or if your current drive is `%HOMEDRIVE%` you could try `\%HOMEPATH%`. `%USERPROFILE%` is just a possible alternative, and whilst it may work for you it doesn't necessarily return the same location, or technically fix your issue. BTW, `%APPDATA%`, depending upon the age of the target OS, may resolve to the users `\AppData\Roaming` location too!

Comment: "%USERPROFILE%" is the default home directory in Windows, i.e. the default location for special folders such as Documents. "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%" is often the same location, but it could be different or even bizarrely incorrect (e.g. with a scheduled task or runas.exe, it may be "%SystemRoot%\System32"). That said, special folders can be relocated by policy in tandem with setting a custom home directory. In this case "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%" may be the correct location, depending on your needs. Unfortunately CMD doesn't provide a way to get the location of special folders. PowerShell does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the appropriate environment variable for your task you can issue in a cmd window (Path excluded for it's length):

```
> set |find /i "%USERNAME%"|find /i /V "Path"

APPDATA=C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local
OneDrive=C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive
TEMP=C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp
USERNAME=UserName
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\UserName
```

But take care, some `special folders` might be relocated to other drives/folders.
You'll need a vb-/Jscript or PowerShell to evaluate these locations.

At a PowerShell prompt:

```
PS> [environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments")
C:\Users\LotPings\Documents
```

To enumerate the special folders names:

```
PS> [Environment+SpecialFolder]::GetNames([Environment+SpecialFolder])
```

And to resolve all special folders to their current values:

```
[Environment+SpecialFolder]::GetNames(
    [Environment+SpecialFolder])| Sort-Object | ForEach-Object{
       "{0,22} {1}" -f $_,[Environment]::GetFolderPath($_)}
```

---

```
AdminTools             C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
ApplicationData        C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming
CDBurning              C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn\Burn
CommonAdminTools       C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
CommonApplicationData  C:\ProgramData
CommonDesktopDirectory C:\Users\Public\Desktop
CommonDocuments        C:\Users\Public\Documents
CommonMusic            C:\Users\Public\Music
CommonOemLinks
CommonPictures         C:\Users\Public\Pictures
CommonProgramFiles     C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFilesX86  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonPrograms         C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
CommonStartMenu        C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
CommonStartup          C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
CommonTemplates        C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
CommonVideos           C:\Users\Public\Videos
Cookies                C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies
Desktop                C:\Users\LotPings\Desktop
DesktopDirectory       C:\Users\LotPings\Desktop
Favorites              C:\Users\LotPings\Favorites
Fonts                  C:\WINDOWS\Fonts
History                C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
InternetCache          C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache
LocalApplicationData   C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Local
LocalizedResources
MyComputer
MyDocuments            C:\Users\LotPings\Documents
MyMusic                C:\Users\LotPings\Music
MyPictures             C:\Users\LotPings\Pictures
MyVideos               C:\Users\LotPings\Videos
NetworkShortcuts       C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
Personal               C:\Users\LotPings\Documents
PrinterShortcuts       C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
ProgramFiles           C:\Program Files
ProgramFilesX86        C:\Program Files (x86)
Programs               C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
Recent                 C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
Resources              C:\WINDOWS\resources
SendTo                 C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
StartMenu              C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
Startup                C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
System                 C:\WINDOWS\system32
SystemX86              C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64
Templates              C:\Users\LotPings\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates
UserProfile            C:\Users\LotPings
Windows                C:\WINDOWS
```

Comment: If a user has a custom home directory for "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%", it may not include the user name. For example, it could be a mapped drive such as "Z:\". Special folders could be relocated there by policy. But I'd use PowerShell to get the location of the "Personal" folder as the "home" directory.